# Looking to at post to a created page on WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm looking to be able to add blog posts to a page I created, as well on the front page too. So, I'd like to have the blog post about sports, show up on my front page and also on my Sports page. Is this possible?

I don't just want to categorize them and tag them, I want it to show on the specific page created for sports.

Any help from you guys would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few links that might help you along.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Try placing this file in your theme folder and choosing it as your template for your page. You'll also need to change the category number at the top. You can refine it further by copying and pasting code from your index.php file in your theme folder. Mix and match elements to get it closer to what you need. Good luck!

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Sports Template
*/

get_header(); 
query_posts( 'cat=3' );

?>
<div id="content" class="widecolumn">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div class="post">
            <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <div class="entrytext">
                    <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page »</p>'); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
</div>
<div id="main">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
        <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
        </ul>   
        <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
        <ul>
                <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
        </ul>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: DeFeNdog, thank you for the links and the code. I'll try it out. Thank you once again.